# Creating a new subsite is taking too long time

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sub-site

Creating a new sub-site from site template is taking approximately **50 minutes** and still working on it.

if I do **IIS reset** before creating new sub-site everything works smooth for whole day and site creating only maximum within **5 minutes**, on the next day again creating site without IIS reset it takes too much long time approx about 50 minutes.

I checked memories in database server that is enough so no issue I think regarding memories also can't find any errors in ULS logs.

Can anybody suggest me the steps to what to do, so no need to reset IIS before creating site.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: is it happening only for this site template or any other operation is also taking time ? Also what all things are included in site template, anything worth mentioning ?

Comment: How is recycling configured in IIS Manager for each web application's application pool? Has this been reconfigured from the default of recycling each application pool daily at a time during the night? (Note that it's common to also run a warm-up script/application immediately afterwards to compile pages and cache them to improve performance) If the application pools are not set to recycle daily, then set them to do so and see if that improves things.

Comment: @siddharth, yes it happening with only site creating from saved site template having some custom lists, collections of event receiver features, custom workflow features, custom webparts etc..

Comment: @Andy Dawson, I have set everyday recycling schedule now, may be will work for now, will let you know, Thanks

Comment: Assuming it works okay for you, it's worth leaving it like it is and adding a warm-up script/application to SharePoint. What works for lots of people is setting the content application pools to recycle once per day at the same time, then run a warm-up script/application a minute later to get SharePoint ready for users to access when they come into work. A very simple one to use is available at http://spwakeup.codeplex.com/ - there's links on the 'Discussions' page to a 2013 version that I provide. There are lots of other examples; use the one that suits you best!

Comment: @Hitesh do you have any custom code deployed in your farm, please put the verbose logs enabled and try to create subsite and monitor logs

Answer (score 3):

Hope to help:
We set the Application Pool to Recycle everyday. You can do that from the IIS Management Console:

1) Locate the App Pool first, and then [click on Recycling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lkqw.jpg)

2) Then you can [set the Recycle Conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJQwR.jpg)

That's a quick way to improve your farm's performance (while you check and fix other potential causes)